# Sync Exchange emails with iPhone

Tags: email, iphone, exchange

Do I have to have any services, etc. enabled on my server so I can sync my iPhone to Microsoft Exchange?

Comment: What version of Microsoft Exchange are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need [ActiveSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_ActiveSync) setup and enabled on your Exchange Server.